# how to yank two level up bracket inside vim

Tags: vimrc, neovim

I have a paragraph in this structure

```
{
// line 4
 {
   //something in here
   {
     // line 8
     // some inner thing in here 
   }
 }
// line 12
}
```

my cursor is in line 8 and I want to yank everything from line 4 up to line 12

I have tried `yi3}` but not worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Count must precede object (`i}` in this case).

Hence, the right command is `y3i}`